# SWT TreeCursor widget created with a preset area

Tags: eclipse, swt

Please see the [Attachment_TreeCursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9zAR.png).
The TreeCursor is created for a Tree inside a FormPage (for a FormEditor).

Create a FormEditor :

```
package test.treecursor.handlers;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor;

public class TestEditor extends FormEditor {

private TestEditorPage page;

@Override
protected Composite createPageContainer(final Composite parent) {
  return super.createPageContainer(parent);
}

@Override
protected void addPages() {
try {
  this.page = new TestEditorPage(this);
  addPage(this.page);
}
catch (PartInitException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

 @Override
  public void doSave(final IProgressMonitor monitor) {    
 }

 @Override
   public void doSaveAs() {   
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isSaveAsAllowed() {  
   return false;
 }
}
```

Create a FormPage :

```
package test.treecursor.handlers;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.TreeCursor;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeColumn;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.IManagedForm;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage;

public class TestEditorPage extends FormPage {

 public TestEditorPage(final TestEditor testEditor) {
   super(testEditor, "1", "MyTitle");
 }

 @Override
 protected void createFormContent(final IManagedForm managedForm) {
   Composite composite = managedForm.getForm().getBody();
   composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
   composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
   Tree tree = createTree(composite);
   createTreeColumns(tree);
   final TreeCursor cursor = new TreeCursor(tree, SWT.BORDER);
 }

 private Tree createTree(final Composite composite) {
  Tree tree = new Tree(composite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
   tree.setLayout(composite.getLayout());
   tree.setLayoutData(composite.getLayoutData());
   tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
   tree.setLinesVisible(true);
   return tree;
 }

 private void createTreeColumns(final Tree tree) {
   TreeColumn column1 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.LEFT);
   column1.setText("First column");
   column1.setWidth(300);
   TreeColumn column2 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.LEFT);
   column2.setText("Second column");
   column2.setWidth(300);
 }
}
```

Add this editor to the editor extension point: org.eclipse.ui.editors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
     <editor
           class="test.treecursor.handlers.TestEditor"
           default="false"
           id="test.treecursor.editor1"
           name="TestEditor">
     </editor>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

If I set the SWT style to SWT.TRANSPARENT, I do not see this 'patch' anymore but I still cannot select the rows in the tree in this area.
It looks like the cursor picks up this size from its parent composite of Form/ScrollableForm. On the Display object of tree.getDisplay(), I can see the field RECT clickRect having values for left, right, bottom and top. Could these be picked up for creation of the cursor? How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Can't reproduce without the rest of the code, you should provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Loris Securo : I have updated the source code with which you can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 problems in the `createTree` method:

1. `tree.setLayout(composite.getLayout());`: it doesn't make sense to set a layout on a `Tree`; a layout is useful to correctly position the children, but in a `Tree` you don't have to do that; this is also specified in the [`Tree` documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FTree.html):

   > Note that although this class is a subclass of Composite, it does not
   >   normally make sense to add Control children to it, or set a layout on
   >   it

   Therefore you should remove the instruction.
2. `tree.setLayoutData(composite.getLayoutData());`: you are trying to re-use the `GridData` of the `Composite`, you can't do that; from the [`GridData` documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridData.html):

   > NOTE: Do not reuse GridData objects. Every control in a Composite that
   >   is managed by a GridLayout must have a unique GridData object.

   You should create another `GridData` object to use only in the `Tree`.

The area you are seeing should disappear once you fix these problems.